# Trouble calculating Fourier Transform of Dirac's Delta function

Tags: fourier-transform, dirac-delta

I've seen some other posts were already posted on this matter, but none of them seem to be oriented to performing the actual fourier transform of $\delta(x)$. I've just been introduced the Fourier transform and I'm having some trouble to check some of its properties, one of the most basic being:

$$\mathcal{F}(\delta) = 1$$

I keep getting a square root factor which I can't seem to get rid of:

$$\mathcal{F}(\delta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i\xi x}\delta(x)\cdot dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{0} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \neq 1$$

Naturally, I get the same result when applying the integral definition of $\delta$:

$$\sqrt{2\pi} \delta(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ix\eta}\cdot d\eta$$

Introducing this expression inside the Fourier transform:

$$\mathcal{F}(\delta)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i\xi x}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ix\eta}\cdot d\eta \right )dx$$

which leads me to the same conclusion as above.

My best guess is this result might be related to the normalisation factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ and not to my understanding of Dirac's delta function, although this could also be true. Quite frankly, I'd like to expand my knowledge of these functions as they are ubiquitous in theoretical Physics, but my plain Physics degree doesn't cover them as much as I'd like. If you could recommend some resources to learn about these useful tools, I'd be more than grateful.

Comment: There are different definitions of the Fourier transform and the inverse Fourier transform that put the normalization factors in different places. You should quote the definition you’re using.

Comment: [Wolfram Delta Function]](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html) refers to the integral of the deta function at a point as the value of that function at that point. To quote:  $int_(-\infty)^\{inftyf(x)}{delta(x-a) dx}=f(a)$.  There is another difficulty taking the "inverse" Fourier transform with a limit from minus infinity to positive infinity of a constant - no limit . The similar Laplace transform may be have a better inverse transform. See [Inverse Laplace of a constant](https://www.mathstoon.com/inverse-laplace-transform-of-constant-1/), which shows the derivation

Comment: @StephenElliott The Fourier transform is a tempered distribution.  And the inverse FT of a constant is NOT the integral of a constant.

Comment: @Mark Viola: Berkley article [Tempered Distributions](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m321/distributions.pdf) has additional insight.  To quote:  The theory of tempered distributions allows us ...rigorous meaning to the Dirac
delta function. It is “defined”...
(i) δ(x) = 0 except when x = 0
(ii) δ(0) is “so infinite” that
(iii) the area under its graph is one."  
From [Appendix D](https://users.physics.ox.ac.uk/~lvovsky/quantumbook/app-d.pdf)
a) in the limit b → 0, Eq. (D.16) takes the form
F[δ(x)] = 1√2π (D.17)
b) in the opposite limit, b → ∞, one obtains
F[1] = √2π δ(k) (D.18)

Comment: @AlanFox86:  When applying Fourier Transforms and Inverse Fourier transforms, I often define these in terms of limits of $b$ approaching $0$, like in the reference:  [Appendix D
Dirac delta function and the Fourier
transformation](https://users.physics.ox.ac.uk/~lvovsky/quantumbook/app-d.pdf) because simply defining the limit of the integral going from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ is not sufficient, because the integral of an ordinary Heavyside function $f(x)=0,x<0; f(x)=1, x \ge 0$ is unbounded as $x \to \infty$ otherwise.  Please let me know if I should write this answer + Scaling constants.